# Understanding inheritance and overriding

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, overriding

Actually my question was kind of answered already but I can't understand it properly. here is a code snippet:

```
public class Superclass {

   public static void main (String[] args){
      Superclass obj = new Subclass();
      obj.doSomething(); #prints "from Superclass"
   }

   private void doSomething(){System.out.println("from Superclass");}
}

class Subclass extends Superclass {

    private void doSomething(){System.out.println("from Subclass");}

}
```

It prints out : "from Superclass"

> Since the reference type of the object obj is SuperClass, a call to
>   doSomething() tries to access the private method defined in SuperClass
>   itself (private methods cannot be overridden). As doSomething() is
>   accessible within SuperClass, the main method can call doSomething()
>   without giving any error/s.

As far as I can imagine the method calling works this way: *(maybe I am totally wrong about this)*:

The instances of an object store only the data in themselves and when I call an instance method Java takes a look at the type of the reference variable and calls the method from the class of that type.
(It seems logical to me and explains why the code above prints "from Superclass")

But changing the access modifier in the first `doSomething()` method to protected confuses me, because I can't understand how Java knows there is an overriding if the reference type is the `SuperClass` and not the `SubClass`. Does overriding change the method in the `Superclass` as well?

Or am I totally wrong about how method calling and overriding works?

I would really appreciate If someone could help me out and explain what I am missing.

Comment: Check out the java documentation about access control [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Private** methods along with **static** methods and all variables cannot be overridden, they can be **hidden**. So you would need to change the access modifier of your method from private to any other access modifier.

N.B: There are a few protocols to follow when overriding a method; The access modifier of the method defined in the sub-class must have the same level of access if not more accessible than the method that is being overridden. Return types must be covariant etc...

Comment: Overriden method doesn't require to have exact same return types. The global things to remember is an overriden method can't change compatibility of method definition. It implies if a method is accessible in a context, the overriden must be at least visible with same constraint but can enlarge it. On the other side, an overriden method can be declared with a more specific return type as it extends the original one and the return type contract is still valid from abstract caller. However, you can't change parameter due to method resolution at compilation.

Comment: Thank you, First I didn't get why Java doesn't look for overridden method in the Subclass and it's because as you said private and static methods can only be hidden. It looks simple now  :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have defined "doSomething" as private method, your override did not work. Change it to public or protected and then see output.

To understand it better, move Subclass in another java file. Now tell me, can you make a private method call from an object handle?

Comment: To add to that, this is an instance where the use of the `@Override`-annotation would have prevented confusion. If OP adds that to his current code, it informs him that nothing is being overwritten by the Subclass-method.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality of overriding a method is simply defining another way to execute the same method using inheritance.

No, overriding **doesn't change at all** the super class (unless you're doing some weird things with reflection, but that's another story).

The **private** keyword is used when only the class itself can "see" the method. On the other hand, the **protected** keyword is used exactly for inheritance: the class **and it's childs** can see the method. That's why you can only override protected methods.